# How to troubleshoot chrome packaged app crash

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've enabled crashes tracking in Settings, but chrome://crashes/ page is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should examine regular Chrome logs.

See [this article](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) on how to enable logging.

It also mentions Sawbuck as a log monitoring utility, which I used in the past to debug a crash in an extension.

Comment: Also, please file a bug at http://crbug.com. If you are getting messages about apps crashing it is usually because you're tickling some bug in chrome.

Comment: @BenWells Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383579/chrome-packaged-app-crashes-after-webrtc-video-chat

Comment: I am getting a lot of user reports of crashes, but do not see them in my own testing. Is there a way to see how many crashes occur in the wild? I don't see any "crashes" in the google analytics for the app, and I'm not sure if it's possible for me to track crashes at all. Any ideas?

Comment: @kzahel When an app/extension crashes (with a popup from Chrome saying so), it crashes completely - ceases to execute. It can't report the crash to analytics and there are no APIs to detect that previous execution ended in a crash.

Comment: I have some ideas of how I might get a rough estimate of how many crashes, for example recording a timestamp every second in chrome.storage.local, and if the app quits unexpectedly (e.g. not by all the windows closing, or receiving onSuspend event), the next time it starts up, it would at least know that it had an unexpected exit. I am pretty certain Android apps can report crashes, it's too bad there is no Chrome platform analogue

Comment: That idea sounds like a serious waste of client CPU cycles. (and unnecessary I/O)

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea, and would welcome an alternative one