# Chrome packaged app crashes after webrtc video chat

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, google-chrome-app

I'm using JavaScript IceLink library (http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/icelink) to implement webrtc video chat. Application crashes sometimes after video chat. Chrome logs shows the next problem:
[240:1520:0819/141151:VERBOSE1:webrtcsession.cc(1016)] SetAudioPlayoutVolume: No audio channel exists.

```
void WebRtcSession::SetAudioPlayoutVolume(uint32 ssrc, double volume) {
  ASSERT(signaling_thread()->IsCurrent());
  ASSERT(volume >= 0 && volume <= 10);
  if (!voice_channel_) {
    LOG(LS_ERROR) << "SetAudioPlayoutVolume: No audio channel exists.";
    return;
  }

  if (!voice_channel_->SetOutputScaling(ssrc, volume, volume))
    ASSERT(false);
}
```

(https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/webrtcsession.cc?r=6855#990)

Looks like - crash - is an expected behavior for Chrome browser, but it is a bad user experience for my application. Can I handle this situation somehow? I need to get rid of this crash.

Comment: Wrong code snippet: the line number does not correspond to this crash, You should be looking at https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/webrtcsession.cc?r=6855#990

Comment: Failed assertions are never expected behavior. They're designed to turn certain classes of unexpected behavior into specifically prohibited behavior. For developers, it means that a user's bug report goes from something mysterious ("my rocket ship exploded") into something described very specifically ("instead of launching, the rocket's control module said 'thrust should never exceed level 10' and then it just sat there on the launch pad"). File a bug with the console output, and the Chromium developers will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a crash is "expected behavior" is an interesting question.

Semantically, an `assert(condition)` kind of statement means

> Unless `condition` is true, something is *very, very wrong*

Apparently, Chrome developers subscribe to the [Crash Early](http://pragmatictips.com/32) philosophy - if you cannot meaningfully recover from a failure state, you are expected to terminate as soon as possible. In that regard, it is "expected" behavior.

---

Then again, if an assert is tripped, this means an error in the program. If this was an expected state, there would not be a crash, but meaningful reaction. Therefore, you're hitting a bug in Chrome, not "expected" behavior. A user should not be able to trigger a crash, even if there is a fault in the library you're using.

You should test your app with the latest Chrome version ([dev](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)/[Canary](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) builds). If the error is still there - it's a clear bug you [should report](https://crbug.com/new). If the error does not reproduce in Canary, it was a bug that's fixed and all you can do is wait for the next Chrome version that has it fixed.

Comment: Please add a link to the bug report if you filed it.