# Chrome crash on device unplug using serial API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I'm making an application for Chrome based on the [serial API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial) in order to send and receive data from a USB device that registers as a virtual serial port.

The problem I'm having is that when I remove the device and the connection is established the browser crashes and I don't have any idea why as the debug console also closes and the Chrome crash reporting (chrome://crashes) isn't showing anything (OSX 10.9.4, Chrome 37.0.2062.94). I suspect a low level exception in Chrome that isn't caught. The best I can do is an [Apple crash report](http://pastebin.com/ttvv4p5q).

Is there any way to prevent the browser from crashing (some check before the browser thinks it's in an illegal state...), I know the simple answer is not to unplug while the device is connected, but I'd like a more monkey-proof solution.

Comment: The _browser_ crashes or you get a popup that your app crashes?

Comment: In any case, see this question: [How to troubleshoot chrome packaged app crash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25380484/934239) and head over to https://crbug.com/

Comment: The whole browser crashes as per the Apple crash report, but I guess it's quite useless to send that report to them. I'll see if I can get more debug data with what you linked.