# How to debug chrome packaged app exiting?

Tags: google-chrome-app

My chrome packaged app appears to either exit or crash after a couple days of running on a windows 7 machine. I've enabled crash logging in chrome but nothing shows up in chrome://crashes so I'm not 100% positive it's even crashing. This usually happens overnight so I'm not around to see exactly what's going on. I'm stuck on how to debug this further, does anybody have any tips or suggestions?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Probably duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380484/how-to-troubleshoot-chrome-packaged-app-crash

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for chrome.runtime.onSuspend event and cancel it by triggering an XHR to some faulty URL